# Doing a simple join on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

team:

```
id    name
1     A
2     B
```

game:

```
id   away_team_id   home_team_id    court
1    1              2               1A
```

I am trying to attain this output:

```
game_id   away_team_name  home_team_name    court
1         A               B                 1A
```

I can do a simple join to receive one of the team names, but how do I get both names in one query?

Comment: Join twice to the team table, once for each name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    game.id AS game_id,
    away_team.name AS away_team_name,
    home_team.name AS home_team_name,
    game.court
FROM
    game
LEFT JOIN team AS away_team
ON
    away_team.id = game.away_team_id
LEFT JOIN team AS home_team
ON
    home_team.id = game.home_team_id
```

You just need to join with the table "team" twice.